# Get string value from a static final Object[] containing Class objects

Tags: android, sdk

I'm using a script from a ListView tutorial and am trying to get some random stuff done, main purpose learning Android SDK. I can't get through one thing...

Piece of the script:

```
private static class Video { public String title;
    public String description;
    public int image;

 .
 .
 .

    public Video(String title, String description, int image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }
}

private static final Object[] OBJECTS = { 
        "Movies",
        new Video("Iron Man 2", "description", R.drawable.ferrari), 
        new Video("Twilight - Chapitre 3 : hasitation"),
                    "Series",
 .
 .
 .
        };
```

I know if i use OBJECTS[0].toString() i get "Movies". But how the heck do i get the first value (title) from the 'new Video()' entry at a current position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do:

```
Video video = (Video) OBJECTS[1];
System.out.println(video.description);
```

Btw encapsulate your data. Usually it's not a good idea to have the class attributes as `public`. Write getters and setters.

Comment: I understand now, it works like a charm!  I will dive into the getters and setters too, thanks for the advice.